# Oracle wildcard not matching?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am querying part numbers from an Oracle (JDE) database. If I use the clause `WHERE Item LIKE 'AS-%'`, it correctly returns all the items that begin with 'AS-'. However, when I try to narrow that set by instead using the clause `WHERE Item LIKE 'AS-%A'` in order to find all parts matching the pattern and ending with an 'A', I get no results, even though they do exist!

What gives?

Comment: Here's the sqlfiddle I created: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d8913/1 -- seems to work.  Possibly your data isn't what you think it is?

Comment: `LIKE 'AS-%A'` is perfect, can you please paste the records you claim didn't match the pattern. Might be it had some spaces in between.!

Comment: What datatype is the string? If it's a `CHAR()` remember that they're padded with spaces on the end of the string

Comment: Thanks, Phil! There were, in fact, spaces at the end of the string!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you think that your query is misidentifying rows based on your understanding of the rows' values, examine the values using the DUMP() function.

This will tell you the exact contents of the cell, including any characters that you cannot see on the display.

Comment: Thanks, David! It hadn't occurred to me that there might be spaces at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt if there is some space or non printable character present at the end of column values.

'AS-%A' must work if value actualy start with AS- and ends with A

To check, try to query using `trim(Item) like 'AS-%A'`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps some control characters at end of the data that you cannot see.  Try using regexp_like:

```
with x as (
  select 'AS-123B' as col from dual
  UNION
  select 'AS-456A' as col from dual
  UNION
  select 'AS-789A' || chr(0) as col from dual
)
select * from x
where regexp_like (col, 'AS-(.*)A[[:cntrl:]]?')
```

Output:

```
COL
AS-456A
AS-789A
```